Fibonacci sequence using recursion
I try to make a function that returns an arrays of fib sequence up to Nth term. I've done this using iteration and returning n-th term alone with recursion but I can't understand how to save the terms in the array using recursion.
I tried with this but it only returns last term and not as an array but a number


function fibRec(n) {

  if (n == 1) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (n == 2) {
    return 1;
  }
  let array = [];
  return (array[n] = fibRec(n - 1) + fibRec(n - 2));
}

console.log(fibRec(10))




What do you want to happen to that array? Your fibRec returns the n-the number, not the array, so who will use that array? Did you intend that array as temporary memoization (but then, you never read from it), or do you want fibRec to return an array (but you actually don't)?

Your array variable is created for each execution of Fib, so you have multiple of them, and every one of them starts out empty, and then gets one assignment to its n index, and is then discarded (since it is local).
Moreover, if you want the caller to get an array, then you'll have to return an array, which you currently don't: all three return statements return a number, not an array.
The first thing to ensure is that you always return an array. But then realise that you cannot just add up the two return values you get from the recursive calls, since they are now ... arrays!
You'll also not make two recursive calls, but just one (with n-1), as it will return you the array that also includes the n-2 entry.
Finally, make sure that you just have one array that is shared by all recursive calls -- so you'd pass it as argument. You can create that array once by using the default value for the second argument.
For instance:


function fibRec(n, array=[0,1]) {
    if (n >= array.length)  { // We didn't calculate it yet
        fibRec(n - 1, array); // Don't perform a sum with returned value
        array[n] = array[n-1] + array[n-2]; // Perform the sum here
    }
    return array; // Always return the array
}

console.log(fibRec(10))



All in all, this is rather clumsy: as you know you have to populate the array incrementally anyway, using a recursion stack is just wasted space. Just go for the iterative version.

your output starts at 1 rather than 0 and you output 1 extra value :p

Yes, I now changed the initialisation to [0,1] instead of [1,1]. But as they assign to array[n], I guess they expect the array to have that index, so 0...n. Either way, whether we stop at n or n-1, it is not going to be a problem for the asker.

In case you're interested in higher numbers and you explicitly want to use recursion, you need a bit more "helpers" for it.
For the recursion part, you need what's called trampolining, it enables you to call tail recursive functions in a stack safe manner in a language that does not support tail recursion.
In regards to the numbers, trincot correctly pointed out that you soon reach a point (last possible Number value is reached at the 1476th position in my tests) where all numbers end in Infinity since they become bigger than Number.MAX_VALUE. Because of that you'd need to return an array of BigInt values rather than Number values which has it's own caveats. Make sure to read about BigInt on MDN so you understand the differences. Again, this is only relevant if you want to compute beyond the 1476th fibonacci number.
Below is an implementation of trampoline helper functions (recur, Loop & Done) and a working example with BigInt that calculates the 10000th number.

You need to look into the browser's console to see the actual
results, the snippet's console only shows null.



const fibRec = (upTo) => recur(
  (done, loop, { values, nextValue }) => {
    return values.length >= upTo // base case, if we reach `upTo` values ...
      ? done(values)             // ... we're done
      : loop({                   // ... otherwise we loop again!
          values: values.concat(nextValue),
          nextValue: values[values.length - 1] + nextValue
        });
  },
  { values: [0n], nextValue: 1n } // start with 0n & 1n
);

console.log(fibRec(10000));




/* --- helpers */
function recur(func, initValue) {
  let result = func(Done, Loop, initValue);
  while (result instanceof Loop) {
    result = func(Done, Loop, result.value);
  }
  return result.value;
};

function Loop(value) {
  const x = Object.create(Loop.prototype);
  x.value = value;
  return x;
};

function Done(value) {
  const x = Object.create(Done.prototype);
  x.value = value;
  return x;
}



OLD, WRONG IMPLEMENTATION
This was the code from my first answer in which I misunderstood that you want N entries and interpreted "... Nth term ..." as a definition for the upper limit that your number should not exceed. Again, thanks to trincot for pointing that out.

I left it to show how little needed to change to make it work,
the only differences are the base case and the start values.



const fibRec = (upTo) => recur(
  (done, loop, { values, nextValue }) => {
    return nextValue >= upTo
      ? done(values)
      : loop({
          values: values.concat(nextValue),
          nextValue: values[values.length - 1] + nextValue
        });
  },
  { values: [0], nextValue: 1 }
);

console.log(fibRec(10000));




/* --- helpers */
function recur(func, initValue) {
  let result = func(Done, Loop, initValue);
  while (result instanceof Loop) {
    result = func(Done, Loop, result.value);
  }
  return result.value;
};

function Loop(value) {
  const x = Object.create(Loop.prototype);
  x.value = value;
  return x;
};

function Done(value) {
  const x = Object.create(Done.prototype);
  x.value = value;
  return x;
}




@trincot Thanks for pointing out the error(s) I made, I changed my answer accordingly so that it now does output 10,000 items (BigInts, but I explicitly mention that) and I included your arguments into it.
